# cups not printing classification

Tags: linux, unix, printing, cups

Our print server is using cups, and it is set to use a classification but the classification is not appearing on the pages.  The banner prints and all config files look to be okay (printers.conf, cupsd.conf, client.conf) and lpoptions shows the job-sheets with the right classification.  We are not using user config files.

So what am I missing here? Why is the classification not working?

Cups version is 1.1.14 running on Solaris 8.

I captured some debug level logs of me printing with all the settings turned on.  You can get them from http://zenorsoft.com/downloads/cups_logs.txt

Comment: Still not working... Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: It was recommended to use the page-label job option, but that did not do anything.  page-label was added in 1.1.7 best I can tell, and I'm running 1.1.14 so it should be there.

Comment: I also turned on debugging when printing and in Startjob: envp string does include CLASSIFICATION=secret.

Not sure what to check next.

Comment: Why is everyone voting to close this? It is a legitimate question that I need an answer too and am doing as much research outside this as possible and keeping the topic updated with what I have tried so far...

Comment: It is a system administration question, not a programming question.   You are more likely to get an answer on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

OMG! You are asking a question about a 10-year-old CUPS release running on a 12-year-old operating system...

Chances are, that no-one else reading this site will have this combo to try and reproduce this problem.

I used CUPS 1.1.14 at the time, and can remember there was a problem with banners when using them with implicit classes.

**So the question is: do you have `ImplicitClasses Yes|On|True` in your `cupsd.conf` ?**

Also: **do you have a PostScript file named `secret` in your `/usr/share/cups/data/banners/` directory ?**

Finally: **The CUPS "classification" does not work for "raw" queues or "raw" jobs.**

Raw queues are those that don't have a PPD associated to them in `/etc/cups/ppd/`. That means any job pushed to them are printed without any filtering applied. Raw jobs are jobs that don't pass any filtering (even if sent to a non-raw queue) because the commandline says `-o raw`...